# How to use "like" with "and" in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to select "XBox 360" and "XBox One" both formats. But the query select "XBox 360" format only.

Here is my SQL query.

```
select id,name,rate_score,rate_number,video_image from products where release_on >= '$bef1mo' and (formats like '%XBox 360%' and formats like '%XBox One%') order by id desc limit 0,4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `or` instead of `and` like as below code.

```
select id,name,rate_score,rate_number,video_image from products where release_on >= '$bef1mo' and (formats like '%XBox 360%' or formats like '%XBox One%') order by id desc limit 0,4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `or` in `(formats like '%XBox 360%' and formats like '%XBox One%'`

```
select id,name,rate_score,rate_number,video_image from products where
    release_on >= '$bef1mo' and 
    (formats like '%XBox 360%' OR formats like '%XBox One%') 
order by id desc limit 0,4
```

Since logical and means both must match (not either).

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use `OR` Not `AND`

```
select id,name,rate_score,rate_number,video_image 
from products 
where release_on >= '$bef1mo' 
and (formats like '%XBox 360%' 
OR formats like '%XBox One%') 
order by id desc limit 0,4
```

AND : Selects BOTH Formats='%XBox 360%' and  Formats='%XBox One%'

OR : select Where Formats '%XBox 360%' OR  Formats='%XBox One%'